# Cannot send facebook apprequest from iOS because FBSession.activeSession.isOpen gives false

Tags: ios, facebook, request

my app can only send app request during the first run that the user logins into facebook. Once the app is restarted, the app request gets stopped because FBSession.activeSession.isOpen gives false.

Although, FBSession.activeSession.isOpen gives false still the app can perform other operations such as posting to the wall, getting friend list etc. Only it cannot send app requests. And still it has a valid access token too.

Any ideas?

Comment: which API u r use for that ?

Comment: Is there any update on this question? I am also getting same issue with my code and not able to solve it using solution given above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say "FBSession.activeSession.isOpen gives false", but, just to be sure : when do you run this test? When your call to the login request returns, or inside the asynchronous request's callback ?

If it's done outside the request's callback, it may say that the session is not opened yet. Then, the request returns properly, which means that any further call to another FB request succeeds.

Does that help?

If it does not, maybe an overview of your code could.

Comment: I check whether FBSession.activeSession.isOpen gives false or not. if then I re-ran the login mechanism and then FBSession.activeSession.isOpen gives true and I'm abel to send app requests.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, next to your comment from the previous answer :

yes, that's what you said already. but WHERE in your code do you check isOpen? To expect a proper value, it should be something like this :

```
FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:_readPerms allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {

        // here is the proper place to check the isOpen boolean, and to go on with your program, including the app request
    }];

// not the proper place to check isOpen.
```

Does that help?